# Delete date objects in JSON field with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, datetime

I have a MySQL table with a column of the type JSON. In this column I have rows with data like this:

```
[{"meeting": "2020-12-02"}, {"meeting": "2020-01-17"}, {"meeting": "2021-01-17"}]
[{"meeting": "2020-08-02"}, {"meeting": "2021-01-17"}]
```

Is it possible to constuct a MySQL query that removes all JSON obejcts with dates that are before date(NOW) ?

It is in a MySQL database version:5.7.31-34

An ID column is also present in the table.

I cannot change the field type away from JSON!

Comment: Wouldn't you be tempted to simply store normalised data?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0, you could use `json_table()` to unnest the json arrays to rows, then filter out past dats, and re-aggregate. You need a primary key for this, I assumed `id`:

```
select id, json_arrayagg(json_object('meeting', x.meeting)) as new_col
from mytable t
cross join json_table (t.col, '$[*]' columns (meeting date path '$.meeting')) x
where x.meeting > current_date
group by id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4558ade5179ad2c86390e5dedac0e711)**:

```
id | new_col                                               
-: | :-----------------------------------------------------
 1 | [{"meeting": "2020-12-02"}, {"meeting": "2021-01-17"}]
 2 | [{"meeting": "2021-01-17"}]
```

---

If you wanted an `update` statement:

```
update mytable t
inner join
    select id, json_arrayagg(json_object('meeting', x.meeting)) as new_col
    from mytable t
    cross join json_table (t.col, '$[*]' columns (meeting date path '$.meeting')) x
    where x.meeting > current_date
    group by id
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.col = t1.new_col
```

Comment: I need to run this on the same column every day to remove outdated dates - so the objects have to remain in the same column.

Comment: @user1621015: no, this requiers MySQL 8.0, as stated in the answer.

Comment: @user1621015: If you want an `update` statement, then see my updated answer.

Comment: Is there any way to acomplish the same in version 5.7 - I cannot change DB version.

Comment: @user1621015: performing such task in pre-8.0 versions is challenging.

Comment: But not impossible ? ;-)